# Why I can't use 'external' keyword in my flutter project when I want to run it on Chrome(WEB)

Tags: flutter, dart

Is external keyword special？Why I can not use it in a web application build?

I write some code like this:

```
@MyClassAnnotation()
class MyTemplate {
  @MyFieldAnnotation()
  external int fieldA;

  @MyFieldAnnotation()
  external int fieldB;

  factory MyTemplate() = _MyTemplate;
}
```

And I write a code generator to generate the implement for 'MyTemplate' Class, including the getter and setter of fieldA and fieldB and so on. The code can work well on platform like Android, IOS and MacOS. But I got this when I want to run my application in Chrome:

```
Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
```

The version of my flutter sdk:

```
Flutter 3.10.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d3d8effc68 (5 weeks ago) • 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
Engine • revision b4fb11214d
Tools • Dart 3.0.1 • DevTools 2.23.1
```